# laravel hasMany comments from a blog relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, foreign-key-relationship

Im very new at using laravel so please be gentle. I have a blog, that has comments. Im using the hasMany to return the comments but I keep getting an empty array.

I have 2 tables; 1) Blog 2) Comments

The comments table tied the blog comment to the correct blog using a blog_id column in the table.

In my Blog model I am calling the following:

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Comments', 'blog_id', 'id');
}
```

But I am getting an invalid argument for foreach. I have tried only using the frogein key, but still no luck.

As I said im new to using laravel and I hope you can understand where im coming from.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

```
@foreach($blog->comments as $comment)
    {{ $comment->body }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of your tables? Did you create via `Migrate`?

Comment: Can you add the missing code with the foreach? I guess you are following the example in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Yes I used Migrate to create the table, I will add it in now sorry

Comment: There's not much we can do for you without knowing both the table structure and how you are fetching the blog entry.

Comment: If you're following conventions you model should be called Comment and not Comments. Maybe that could be it(?)

Comment: @Adam follow the advice of the commenters ^^^ correct convention and also if you do `dd ($ blog-> comments)` you might see what is going wrong